# Calling web service from ASP.NET web app in Azure App service error (httpclient.SendAsync)

Tags: asp.net, azure-web-app-service

I have an ASP.NET app running in AZURE as app service. This app uses HTTP Client to call an external API. It uses standard HTTP Client object to make a POST call. It runs fine if deployed to Azure on a VM but when deployed as App Service, it throws error when calling
httpclient.SendAsync(request). The error is very generic - "An error occurred while sending the request". Since the code works everywhere else (local dev env, deployed to AZURE VM server), I guess it is some limitation of Azure App Service env. The app service is .NET, ASP.NET 4.8, 64Bit configuration. I have to believe that many apps like this have been deployed to Azure App services.

Here are the relevant lines of code:

```
 public  async Task<T> MakeWebServiceCall<T>(String my_input_data, Uri webServiceUri)
 {
  HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage();
  request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, webServiceUri);
  request.Headers.Add("Accept", "*/*");
  var collection = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
  string paramvalue = System.Net.WebUtility.UrlDecode(my_input_data);
  collection.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("data", paramvalue));
  var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(collection);
  request.Content = content;
  request.Content.Headers.ContentType = System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
   HttpMessageHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler
        {
            SslProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls11 | System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12 | System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls,
            ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true,
        };
        HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient(handler);
    httpclient.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0,0,5);
    var response_result = await httpclient.SendAsync(request); // ***   This throws error  *****
    response_result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
   var response_result_final = await  response_result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            
  JsonSerializerSettings JSONFormatSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
  JSONFormatSettings.DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat;
  T result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(response_result_final, JSONFormatSettings);
  return result;

}
```

I have tried changing various settings in AZURE portal for APP service configuration (HTTP versions, TLS versions, .NET versions) etc.

I have try catch and bunch of code to log progress of the code after all calls to the Http client and request objects.  That is how I got the the exact line and the error. And since it works every where else, I think there is some factor in AZURE App service. I guess there is some thing during hand shake in Azure App Service which is the problem.
I hope someone else has come across this in AZURE App service asp.net app.
AS mentioned above, it works WHEN DEPLOYED TO AZURE VM SERVER. So code and called web service etc is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to check timeout settings and logging.

```html
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5); // Set an appropriate timeout
```

Add logging to capture more details about the error. You can log the exception details to get more insights into the specific issue.

```html
try
{
    var response_result = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
    response_result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    // Process the response
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Log the exception details
    Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
}
```

Comment: I did try httpClient time out. The error is thrown right away so time is not an issue. And I do have try catch in the code. That is how I got the error.  I will add comments to the main question with all things I have already tried.